# Project not working after moving to WSL directory

Tags: server, docker, laravel

My dockerized Lumen project had slow response time so according to advices I moved my project from my classic path C:\Mgr\lumen_laravel\lumenmysql to \ \wsl.localhost\Ubuntu\home\samo\lumenmysql, then created Z:\ drive so I can open terminal in that location and run "docker-compose up -d".
In previous adress it was working.I didnt change any code and have got error. Any advices? Thank you.

**error in docker**

> 2023-03-21 22:49:00 AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [/var/www/html/public] does not exist

According to docker inspect Mount info [it exists](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imtSz.png)

> /VAR/WWW/HTML   Z:\home\samo\lumenmysql

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.8'

services:


   mysqldb:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name : mysqldb
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ${DOCKER_MYSQL_VOLUME:-/opt/db_data}:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
     MYSQL_DATABASE: diplomovka
     MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 1234

   phpmyadmin:
     image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
     container_name: phpmyadmin
     environment:
       PMA_HOST: mysqldb
       DB_READ_HOST: mysqldb
     ports:
       - "3400:80"
     depends_on:
       - mysqldb

   app:
     container_name: Lumen
     build:
       context: .
       dockerfile: Dockerfile
     volumes:
       - ./:/var/www/html
     restart: ${DOCKER_RESTART_POLICY:-always}
     ports:
       - "9000:80"
     working_dir: /var/www/html
     environment:
       MYSQL_HOST: mysqldb
       MYSQL_USER: root
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: 1234
       MYSQL_PORT: 3306
```

**vhost.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public

    <Directory "/var/www/html">
        AllowOverride all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM php:7.4.19-apache

WORKDIR /var/www/html

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y  \
        zlib1g-dev \
        libzip-dev \
        libonig-dev \
        curl \

    && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql \
    && docker-php-ext-install mysqli \
    && docker-php-source delete

COPY ./vhost.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

COPY ./ ./

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html \
    && a2enmod rewrite

RUN cd /var/www/html && composer install && php artisan key:generate
```

Comment: The error is in a Linux format and your info is in a Windows format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was

```
volumes:
- \\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu\home\samo\lumenmysql:/var/www/html
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem between the path mapping between your `WSL2` env and your windows `env`, using the `Z:\` drive instead of the `/mnt/c` path.

Here is your updated `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3.8'

services:

   mysqldb:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name : mysqldb
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ${DOCKER_MYSQL_VOLUME:-/opt/db_data}:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
     MYSQL_DATABASE: diplomovka
     MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 1234

   phpmyadmin:
     image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
     container_name: phpmyadmin
     environment:
       PMA_HOST: mysqldb
       DB_READ_HOST: mysqldb
     ports:
       - "3400:80"
     depends_on:
       - mysqldb

   app:
     container_name: Lumen
     build:
       context: .
       dockerfile: Dockerfile
     volumes:
       - /mnt/c/Mgr/lumen_laravel/lumenmysql:/var/www/html
     restart: ${DOCKER_RESTART_POLICY:-always}
     ports:
       - "9000:80"
     working_dir: /var/www/html
     environment:
       MYSQL_HOST: mysqldb
       MYSQL_USER: root
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: 1234
       MYSQL_PORT: 3306
```

Comment: Thank you but this didnt help. At the moment the project is in this directory: \wsl.localhost\Ubuntu\home\samo\lumenmysql or created drive Z:\home\samo\lumenmysql . Not here C:\Mgr\lumen_laravel\lumenmysql . So i cant use /mnt/c/Mgr/lumen_laravel/lumenmysql becouse there is nothing. If i understand it right I need to use something like /mnt/z/home/samo/lumenmysql:/var/www/html but it looks like i dont have Z in mnt.